# PGFPLOTS How to add an extra xtick or vertical line at the correct location?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to add a vertical line at the coordinate x= 3.5 to illustrate that this is the actual thickness configuration. However the attempt below does not put the tick at the right position on the axis. Ideally, in addition to the vertical line, I would like to add a note such as "actual".

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
{Thickness (mm)};{Trise ambient temp};{T-rise at max.temp};{T-rise ambient (narrow)};{T-rise max temp. (narrow)}
3;30;51;46;79
4;21;37;33;56
5;16;28;25;43
6;13;23;20;34
7;11;19;16;28
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=.6\textwidth, width=\textwidth,
thick,
smooth,
grid=both,
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]0},
extra x ticks={3.5}, % does not work, puts a tick between 6 and 7, with label "3"
xlabel={Thickness (\si{\milli\meter})},
ylabel={T-rise (\si{\celsius)}},
]
\addplot [gray,] table [
x expr=\coordindex, x index =0,
y index=1] {\datatable}
[sloped, font=\small]
node[below, pos=0.25] {T-rise at \SI {0}{\celsius}};
\addplot [blue,] table [
x expr=\coordindex, x index =0,
y index=2] {\datatable}
[sloped, font=\small]
node[above, pos=0.25] {T-rise at \SI {180}{\celsius}};
%\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}); draws a vertical line, but at x=4
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `x expr=\coordindex,` to plot  the coordinate index
versus some y data. But here you are plotting the column zero (as x) versus columns one and two (as y). Hence you shouldn't use `x expr`. Since you do, the extra tick at 3.5 appears at `\coordindex` 3.5 where you have x label from the table. (which is 6.5).

Bottom line: remove  `x expr=\coordindex,`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}  %% loaded by pgfplotstable.
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
{Thickness (mm)};{Trise ambient temp};{T-rise at max.temp};{T-rise ambient (narrow)};{T-rise max temp. (narrow)}
3;30;51;46;79
4;21;37;33;56
5;16;28;25;43
6;13;23;20;34
7;11;19;16;28
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=.6\textwidth, width=\textwidth,
thick,
smooth,
grid=both,
xtick=data,
%xticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]0},
xlabel={Thickness (\si{\milli\meter})},
ylabel={T-rise (\si{\celsius)}},
extra x ticks={3.5},
extra tick style={grid=major,major grid style={red,thick},
tick label style={
rotate=90,anchor=east}},
extra x tick labels={Actual},
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]0},
]
\addplot [gray,] table [
 x index =0,
y index=1] {\datatable}
[sloped, font=\small]
node[below, pos=0.25] {T-rise at \SI {0}{\celsius}};
\addplot [blue,] table [
x index =0,
y index=2] {\datatable}
[sloped, font=\small]
node[above, pos=0.25] {T-rise at \SI {180}{\celsius}};
%\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}); draws a vertical line, but at x=4
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]